# Слишком сильная нагрузка программы

Tags: python, циклы

Всё время сталкиваюсь с излишней нагрузкой на прцессор при работе своего кода (как в виде кода так и в exe). Из идей только то что всё из-за бесконечного цикла и постоянной его обработки, пытался пофиксить ивентами но не вышло. Люди знающие, помогите, надо снизить нагрузку и оставить бесконечную работу.
Код:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import mouse
import json

with open("spammer_conf.json", encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

counter_1 = 0
counter_2 = 0
counter_3 = 0
spamstr = data["spamstr"]
emoji = data["emoji"]
button_spam_str = data["button_spam_str"]
button_spam_emoji = data["button_spam_emoji"]
clicker = data["clicker"]
clicker_timeout = data["clicker_timeout"]
button_clicker = data["button_clicker"]
reset = data["reset"]
print(f"Установленые бинды:\nReset: {reset}\nClicker: {clicker}\nСпам текста: {button_spam_str}\nСпам эмоджи: {button_spam_emoji} \nПриятного использования (version 1.2)")

while True:
    e = keyboard.is_pressed(button_spam_emoji)
    s = keyboard.is_pressed(button_spam_str)
    c = keyboard.is_pressed(clicker)
    r = keyboard.is_pressed(reset)
    if e != False:
        keyboard.write(f"{emoji}\n")
        print(f"Спам эмоджи {emoji}: {counter_1 + 1}")
        sleep(0.01)
        counter_1 = counter_1 + 1
    elif s != False:
        keyboard.write(f"{spamstr}\n")
        print(f"Спам строки: {counter_2}")
        sleep(0.01)
        counter_2 = counter_2 + 1
    elif c != False:
        mouse.click(button=button_clicker)
        print(f"Спам кнопкой мыши {button_clicker}: {counter_3 + 1}")
        sleep(0.01)
        counter_3 = counter_3 + 1
    elif r != False:
        counter_1 = 0
        counter_2 = 0
        counter_3 = 0
        print("Все счётчики сброшены")
        sleep(2)
```

(Программированием увлёкся недавно, камнями прошу не кидаться)

Comment: «пытался пофиксить ивентами но не вышло» — почему не вышло?

Comment: Добавьте в цикл sleep(0.01) снаружи if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, Вы хотите как только пользователь нажал нужную кнопку, тут же отправить сообщения. Как можно быстрее и больше. Но вот беда, человек не машина и время реакции у него не нулевое. Большинство людей обычно могут среагировать на 0.3-0.4 секунды, а водители-профессионалы - до 0.25 (тут время реакции - это время между тем, как они увидели изменение ситуации и начали реагировать - крутить руль/жать педали).

Вывод, если сделать опрос раз в 0.1 секунды, 99% пользователей не увидит разницы с 0.01 секундой. Думаю, даже для 0.2 секунды разница будет практически не ощутимой.

Поэтому, выносим мелкие sleep с if и переносим их за их пределы.

```
while True:
    e = keyboard.is_pressed(button_spam_emoji)
    s = keyboard.is_pressed(button_spam_str)
    c = keyboard.is_pressed(clicker)
    r = keyboard.is_pressed(reset)
    if e != False:
        keyboard.write(f"{emoji}\n")
        print(f"Спам эмоджи {emoji}: {counter_1 + 1}")
        counter_1 = counter_1 + 1
    elif s != False:
        keyboard.write(f"{spamstr}\n")
        print(f"Спам строки: {counter_2}")
        counter_2 = counter_2 + 1
    elif c != False:
        mouse.click(button=button_clicker)
        print(f"Спам кнопкой мыши {button_clicker}: {counter_3 + 1}")
        counter_3 = counter_3 + 1
    elif r != False:
        counter_1 = 0
        counter_2 = 0
        counter_3 = 0
        print("Все счётчики сброшены")
    sleep(0.2)
```

нагрузка на процессор сильно уменьшиться. Но вот и слать теперь больше 5 элементов спама в секунду не получится. Может оно и к лучшему. Но если все таки хочется, то кто мешает сделать цикл?

Вместо

```
keyboard.write(f"{emoji}\n")
```

написать

```
for i in range(1,10): # 10000, если здоровье позволяет
  keyboard.write(f"{emoji}\n")
```

если хочется, что бы скорость была повыше, в терминал лучше не писать - это очень затратная операция и может существенно увеличить время, когда за Вами приедут.

Comment: Ну, лично я нажимаю клавиши на клавиатуре за 30-40 миллисекунд (как раз измерял это на днях)

Comment: одно дело, если печатать текст, другое дело, если на экране пишут какую букву нажать и Вы ее жмете.

Comment: @KoVadim Мне важна не точность а скорость. Да и цикл for вроде фиксированное количество повторов

Comment: то есть, задача налить как можно больше сообщений/кликов мыши?

Comment: @KoVadim Ну не то что бы как можно больше - задача делать это по бинду и просто выходя за рамки человеческих возможностей (делаю чтоб людей бесить)

Comment: а зачем? Но если Вам людей подоставать, тогда не вижу причин, почему бы не погреть свой проц.

Comment: @KoVadim В том числе и в играх а при такой нагрузке кадры проседают, поэтому и пытаюсь пофиксить

Comment: как человек, который работает со стороны игр, при быстром спаме в чатах очень часто просто подрезают возможность писать сообщения. Хотите больше - покупайте больше проц.